# atom text editor auto complete not picking up my .css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm using atom text editor 1.20.1 using it for the first time

packages i'm using are: 1.autocomplete-paths 2.emmet 3. and all the core packages

i have my html webpage file sorted like this:[website test folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTCKr.png%5C)

my promblem is when i add link attribute and try to link my css it wont pop up on auto complete but my js files will showed here:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pFwf.png)

[image]

is there a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `config.cson` file:

```
{
  scopes: ['source.css'], // Only triggers in CSS files 
  prefixes: [
    'import\\s+.*?from\\s+[\'"]', // import foo from ' 
    'require\\([\'"]', // require(' 
    'define\\(\\[?[\'"]' // define([' or define(' 
  ],
  extensions: ['css'], // Shows Css files 
  relative: true, // Inserts relative paths only - defaults to true 
  includeCurrentDirectory: true, // Include './' in path - defaults to true 
  replaceOnInsert: [ // Replaces the file extensions on insert 
    ['.css?$', '']
  ]
}
```

Comment: Don´t work for me =( I need help please - just  copy and paste this code in config.cson already work?